# Probability with and without replacement

Tags: probability

Consider an urn with 6 blue and 4 red counters in it... 
i.) With replacement, find the probability that when 2 counters are withdrawn, they are both red.

ii.)Without replacement, find the probability that they are the same colour.

iii.) What is the probability that the first counter was red given at least one is red?

Part i) I drew the tree diagram and found P(R and R) = 16/100 
Part ii) I found the answer to be 0.467 but i am not sure for it. 
Part iii) I have no clue how to do?

Can any help me in part part ii and iii ?

Thank you,

Comment: Your solution for ii.) looks fine.

Comment: How did you do iii tho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let´s define the events:

A=first counter is red.

B: At least one counter is red.

Then $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Note that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$. Thus $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$

Answer (score 0):

For $3$ the favourable outcomes are (a) Red and Blue and (b) red and red

Required probability without replacement:$\frac{6}{10}\times \frac{4}{9}+\frac{6}{10}\times \frac{5}{9}$